# Convert an array of dicts to array of arrays based on dicts values

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array:

```
[{'id_1': 5}, {'id_2': 10}, {'id_2': 4}]
```

And I want the output as:

```
[
 [5],
 [10,4]
]
```

I tried looping and creating specific arrays to track the used indexes but I feel that there should be a more performant way that's O(n) instead of O(n2)

Comment: Plotting charts on Chartist, so this becomes my Series for 2 different lines identified by ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for a `O(n)` solution:

```py
l = [{'id_1': 5}, {'id_2': 10}, {'id_2': 4}]

from collections import defaultdict
dic = defaultdict(list)
for d in l:
    for k,v in d.items():
        dic[k].append(v)

out = list(dic.values())
```

Output: `[[5], [10, 4]]`

Variant with `setdefault`:

```py
dic = {}
for d in l:
    for k,v in d.items():
        dic.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
out = list(dic.values())
```